# Does the span of a set of a vectors set always cover the whole space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, graphing-functions

Suppose we have $V= \{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{p}\},v_{i} \in R^{n}$  vectors set .
Span of $V$ is the set of all possible linear combinations of $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}, ,…,v_{p}$ for some $C= \{c_{1}, c_{2}, ..., c_{p}\}$ scalars.
Questions:
 If we don't fix the scalars $C= \{c_{1}, c_{2}, ..., c_{p}\}$, and let them to be any value from $R$ - $c_{i} \in R$, does the span covers all the $R^{n}$ space ? (for 2d - the whole 2d plane) ?
And if we fix the $C$ set, does the span always plots a line in $R^n$ ?
Can we have an example say for $R^2$ case, when a span plots a plane in 2d (doesn't cover the whole 2d plane) ?
Supposing all the vectors don't lie on the same line.

Comment: Span of $V$ is the set of *all* possible linear combinations of $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}, ,…,v_{p}$, not only for *some* $C= \{c_{1}, c_{2}, ..., c_{p}\}$ scalars.   The scalars are by no mean fixed.

Comment: Please review your question. See former comment.

Comment: Scalars are not elements of $\mathbb R^n $ if $n>1$.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank You, I fixed it.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe So can we have an example say for R2R2 case, when a span plots a plane in 2d (doesn't cover the whole 2d plane, just a subspace) ? Or we always got the whole space for the span, when the vectors don't lie on the same line ?

Comment: The latter, if we are in $2$-space.